# How To Add Content To JQuery Flot Chart Data Array ToolTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a JQuery Flot Line Chart. I have not used JQuery Flot Charts before, and have little experience with JQuery Flot Charts. I have looked around, and cannot find answer to this elsewhere.

The data array for the JQuery Flot line chart is as follows:

```
var twitter = [[1, 27], [2, 34], [3, 51]]
```

When user hovers over each data point in line chart, user is presented with a ToolTip. The ToolTip currently displays the following:

ToolTip Example, Data Point One > Twitter: | X:1 | y:27.00

I can see that this is controlled in the Var Options here:

```
var options = {
                        grid : {
                            hoverable : true
                        },
                        colors : ["#568A89", "#3276B1"],
                        tooltip : true,
                        tooltipOpts : {
                            **//content : "Value <b>$x</b> Value <span>$y</span>",**
```

Now, each of my data arrays are displaying a different point of data. For example:

Data Array One:   Displaying Number of User Profile Views
Data Array Two:   Displaying Number of User Points
Data Array Three: Displaying Number of Friends

Now, when user hovers of each of these data points, user needs to be able to see what each data point relates to.

For example:

When user hovers over > Data Array One: [1, 27]

ToolTip needs to display > 27 Profile Views

When user hovers over > Data Array Two: [2, 34]

ToolTip needs to display > 34 User Points

How can i customize what the ToolTip displays ?

How can i have different ToolTip Content for each individual data array ?

Thank you for your help and support with this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are obtaining the display for each tooltip but in this example it is static. Something like this should work. Fiddle here- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zxtFc/233/)

```
var tickVals = [[1,"Profile Views"],[2,"User Points"],[3,"Number of Friends"]]

var dataLines = [
{
 label: "Twitter",
 data: [[1, 27], [2, 34], [3, 51]],

}
];



$.plot($("#placeholder"), dataLines, {

grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      mouseActiveRadius: 10

},


lines: {show: true},

points: {

    show: true,
    radius: 4
},

});


function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y - 40,
            left: x - 10,
            border: '1px solid #fdd',
            padding: '2px',
            'background-color': '#eee',
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }



    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#placeholder").on("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
        $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
        $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
        if (item) {

            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0]-1,
                        y = item.datapoint[1];

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                                tickVals[x][1] + "- " + y);

            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }

     });
```

Comment: Hi Blake. Thank you for your help. I am using a HTML template that has the JQuery Flot Chart in it. You can view the template here > http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/#ajax/dashboard.html . I am using the Flot Chart on The Dashboard page on > Tab 2 > Social Network. If you view > Page Source, you can see how the Flot Chart is setup. I need to know how to customize the ToolTips on the Flot Chart. So each ToolTip has different content in for the data point it represents. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding the question above. I need to know how to have the ToolTip display: Data Point one > 27 Profile Views , Data Point Two > 34 Friends. I would just like to know how it is possible to customize the content of each individual ToolTip. I am generating the numeric data array value for each data array from some PHP code for my users as i am developing this into a Joomla template, and using some PHP code to create the data arrays. Your JS Fiddle example is what i am trying to achieve with the ToolTips Content. Thank you again.

Comment: I have just noticed, the link i posted to the template, links to the Ajax version of the template, and i cannot see the Flot Chart setup / config in the Page Source. I am using a HTML version of this template where you can view the Flot Chart setup & config in the bottom of the Page Source. Thank you again! You help & support is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Change your plothover event to something similar and that should work.